# Is union is regular expression different from union in set?

Tags: set, computation-theory

In mathematical set we have

A={1,2,3}
B={4,5,6}

A U B = B U A = {1,2,3,4,5,6} ={6,5,2,3,4,1} //order does not matter

But in theory of computation we get

a u b is either a or b but not both

also in a* u b* we get aaa or bbb but not aaabbb or bbbaaa as order does not matter in union.

why is that?

Thanks
Rahman

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In formal language theory, there is a correspondence between regular expressions and regular sets over an alphabet `Σ`. The function `L` maps a regular expression `u` to the corresponding regular set `L(u)`; conversely, every every regular set `A` corresponds to a regular expression in `L-1(A)`:

```
L(∅)   = ∅
L(λ)   = {λ}
L(a)   = {a}              (for all a ∈ Σ)
L(uv)  = L(u)L(v)       = {xy ∈ Σ* : x ∈ L(u) ∧ x ∈ L(v)}
L(u|v) = L(u) ∪ L(v)    = {x ∈ Σ* : x ∈ L(u) ∨ x ∈ L(v)}
L(u*)  = ∪[i ∈ ℕ] L(u)i = ∪[i ∈ ℕ] {xi ∈ Σ* : x ∈ L(u)}
```

The union of regular expressions corresponds to the union of regular sets, which is the familiar union operation from set theory. A regular expression `u` matches a string `x` iff `x` is a member of the corresponding set `L(u)`. Therefore, `u|v` matches `x` iff `x` is a member of `L(u) ∪ L(v)`.

Answer (score -2):

This probably still belongs on math overflow, and you haven't really supplied enough context for a definitive answer so I'm going to make some assumptions.

`Union Types` in most languages might give you an expression like:

```
type C = B union A
```

So type C is the type/set of all values that might exist in the types B or C. So a value x of type B is also a value of type C.

And this is indeed the case for many languages. However stack overflow is targeting the more concrete world of programming. Math overflow is will have more theorists that will be better able to answer your question.